# How can I remove background color of button when clicking outside?

Tags: html, css, button, bootstrap-4

I created a search bar with a category dropdown button in it. I was able to remove the button's background color in it's hover, active, focus and other states. However, when I click outside the button to close the dropdown, the button gets its background color again. How can I remove it? (I'm using Bootstrap 4)

When I click on it, it looks great:

[image]

When I click outside, the button gets a background color:

[image]

```css
.nh-searchbar-category-dropdown-btn {
  border: none;
  position: relative;
  left: 55px;
  color: $secondary-color;
}


/* This is how I'm hidding the background color */

.nh-searchbar-category-dropdown-btn:hover,
.nh-searchbar-category-dropdown-btn:active,
.nh-searchbar-category-dropdown-btn:focus,
.nh-searchbar-category-dropdown-btn:focus:focus-within,
.nh-searchbar-category-dropdown-btn:visited,
.nh-searchbar-category-dropdown-btn:target,
.nh-searchbar-category-dropdown-btn:focus:focus-visible {
  background-color: transparent !important;
  color: $primary-color !important;
  transition: none !important;
  border: none !important;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn btn-outline-secondary dropdown-toggle nh-searchbar-category-dropdown-btn" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
  <i class="far fa-bars"></i>
</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using bootstrap and trying to go against it.

Try to use only these classes:

```
<button class="btn btn-link YOUR CLASSES EXCEPT nh-searchbar-category-dropdown-btn" type="button">
  <i class="far fa-bars"></i>
</button>
```